# Javascript - only first parameter passed when using apply for resolve in promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to call the resolve function in a given promise with an array of parameters using the apply function in Javascript. However, only the first parameter is passed, and the rest are undefined.  Minimal example:

```
const p = function(){
return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
resolve.apply(null,["a1","a2","a3"]);
});
};

p().then(function(a1,a2,a3){
console.log(a1);
console.log(a2);
console.log(a3);
});
```

The above gives output:

```
a1
undefined
undefined
```

What am i missing in the above example?

Comment: Yeah, `resolve` only accepts one parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve` only accepts one argument. If you want to pass more than one thing you'll need to wrap it in a data structure like an array or an object.

Answer (score 2):

Since resolve only accepts a single argument, (and `.then(fn` callbacks only take one argument), you could simply

```js
const p = function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(["a1", "a2", "a3"]);
  });
};

p().then(function([a1, a2, a3]) {
  console.log(a1);
  console.log(a2);
  console.log(a3);
});
```